# Creating a temporary table speed up my database call immensely, why is this?

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

I am unbelievably confused right now.

I have a website that has a large amount of data in multiple tables in my database.  Normally this shouldn't be a problem from what I have read. Apparently that was not the case.

Here is my query for table `d`

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
    d.id,
    d.user__id,
    d.submit_date,
    d.title,
    d.view_count,
    d.vote_count
FROM d
WHERE d.submit_date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
AND d.title != 'No Deck Title'
AND d.is_private != 1
ORDER BY d.id DESC
LIMIT 15;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

I have an `INDEX()` on `submit_date` and my `PRIMARY_KEY` is `id` with `user__id` being a foreign key linked to the `user` table at `user.id`.

Running this query along would take upwards of 30 seconds. I have no idea why this is happening. For no reason I switched the query to this:

```
DROP temporary table IF EXISTS paging;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE paging AS 
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS d.id,
    d.user__id,
    d.submit_date,
    d.title,
    d.view_count,
    d.vote_count
FROM d
WHERE d.submit_date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
AND d.title != 'No Title'
AND d.is_private != 1
ORDER BY d.id DESC
LIMIT 15;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();

SELECT p.id, p.title, p.submit_date, p.view_count, p.vote_count, u.username FROM paging p
INNER JOIN user u on p.user__id = u.id;
```

This pulls the same exact result sets in 0.032 sec, accordingly to my last call on Workbench.

Can someone please explain to me why this is happening, and if this is a normal thing to do for tables with large amounts of data?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be tested by others. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions. Keep in mind that MySQL uses caches, so it might be that the second code will load data from the cache loaded/filled by the first code.

Comment: Note also that in addition to the above, questions about query performance also require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: And ideally the SHOW CREATE TABLE table structure for every table involved in the question

Comment: Also provide information on which MySQL version you are running.